# Unexpected output from map of list column

Tags: r, dplyr, nested, tidyverse, tibble

Below is the output of my code, and my desired output. I only expect each character vector to be printed out, however it prints both character vectors, and then it also prints out the entire list column. Why does this happen, and what should I change to get my desired output?

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~x,  ~y,
  "a", rep("yes", 10),
  "b", rep("no", 10)
)

map(data$y, ~ print(.x))
#>  [1] "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes"
#>  [1] "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no"
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no"
```

Desired output:

```
#>  [1] "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes"
#>  [1] "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no" "no"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lapply`/`map` will always return a value. So you are telling it to `print` the value and it also returns the value which is passed so you get two output. So you can just use `.x` to get one of them.

```
purrr::map(data$y, ~ .x)
```

which is same as

```
data$y
```